# Passing XML to Popup window

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I'm using classic asp, and I would like to pass an xml to the popup window, change something on it and send it back to the parent. Is this possible?

Also, is it possible from the popup to edit the xml on the parent window directly?

Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET or classic ASP with VB Script and no .NET at all?

Comment: Ither vbscript or javascript. no .net at all.